# Query Builder Visual Studio 2005

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2005, query-builder

I'm trying to create an Oracle Select that I've made. But when I save it on Visual Studio Query Builder (VS 2005), the query changes into another one (and it's wrong).

I try to paste it:

```
SELECT ITEM, NM_MNEMONICO, CD_EXA_LAB, NM_EXA_LAB, EXAME
  FROM VDIC_LOG_EXAMES_LAB_DE LA
 WHERE ((PEDIDO = :Pedido) or (:Pedido IS NULL))
   AND ((CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO) OR (:CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL))
UNION ALL
SELECT C.CD_ITPED_LAB_RX,
       E.NM_MNEMONICO,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB,
       E.NM_EXA_LAB,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB EXPR1
  FROM CUSTOM.LOG_MOVIMENTO_EXAME C
 INNER JOIN EXA_LAB E
    ON C.CD_EXA_LAB = E.CD_EXA_LAB
 WHERE ((C.CD_PED_LAB_RX = :Pedido) or (:Pedido IS NULL))
   AND (C.DS_MOVIMENTO LIKE '%Deleted exam%')
   AND ((C.CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO) OR (:CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL))
 ORDER BY 2
```

When I confirm, it gets into this:

```
SELECT        ITEM, NM_MNEMONICO, CD_EXA_LAB, NM_EXA_LAB, EXAME
FROM            VDIC_LOG_EXAMES_LAB_DE LA
WHERE        (PEDIDO = :Pedido) AND (CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO OR
                         :CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL) OR
                         (CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO OR
                         :CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL) AND (:Pedido IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT        C.CD_ITPED_LAB_RX, E.NM_MNEMONICO, E.CD_EXA_LAB, E.NM_EXA_LAB, E.CD_EXA_LAB AS EXPR1
FROM            CUSTOM.LOG_MOVIMENTO_EXAME C, EXA_LAB E
WHERE        C.CD_EXA_LAB = E.CD_EXA_LAB AND ((C.CD_PED_LAB_RX = :Pedido) AND (C.DS_MOVIMENTO LIKE '%Exame excluído da Amostra%') AND 
                         (C.CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO OR
                         :CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL) OR
                         (C.DS_MOVIMENTO LIKE '%Deleted exam%') AND (C.CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO OR
                         :CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL) AND (:Pedido IS NULL))
ORDER BY 2
```

The problem is that this new query doesn't represent what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone know what I can do? Is there a way to preserve my own query **without** any changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put some extra parentheses? I mean, something like this:

```
SELECT ITEM, NM_MNEMONICO, CD_EXA_LAB, NM_EXA_LAB, EXAME
  FROM VDIC_LOG_EXAMES_LAB_DE LA
 WHERE (((PEDIDO = :Pedido) or (:Pedido IS NULL))
   AND ((CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO) OR (:CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NULL)))
```

**[[EDIT]]**

If you have already tried to add some parentheses to "preserv" your Sql Query and didn't work, maybe the only and faster way would be break your Select into two Select's. You could do:

If (*SomeCondition*) {

```
SELECT ITEM, NM_MNEMONICO, CD_EXA_LAB, NM_EXA_LAB, EXAME
  FROM VDIC_LOG_EXAMES_LAB_DE LA
 WHERE (PEDIDO = :Pedido)
UNION ALL
SELECT C.CD_ITPED_LAB_RX,
       E.NM_MNEMONICO,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB,
       E.NM_EXA_LAB,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB EXPR1
  FROM CUSTOM.LOG_MOVIMENTO_EXAME C
 INNER JOIN EXA_LAB E
    ON C.CD_EXA_LAB = E.CD_EXA_LAB
 WHERE (C.CD_PED_LAB_RX = :Pedido)
   AND (C.DS_MOVIMENTO LIKE '%Deleted exam%')
 ORDER BY 2
```

} else {

```
SELECT ITEM, NM_MNEMONICO, CD_EXA_LAB, NM_EXA_LAB, EXAME
  FROM VDIC_LOG_EXAMES_LAB_DE LA
 WHERE (CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO)
UNION ALL
SELECT C.CD_ITPED_LAB_RX,
       E.NM_MNEMONICO,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB,
       E.NM_EXA_LAB,
       E.CD_EXA_LAB EXPR1
  FROM CUSTOM.LOG_MOVIMENTO_EXAME C
 INNER JOIN EXA_LAB E
    ON C.CD_EXA_LAB = E.CD_EXA_LAB
 WHERE (C.DS_MOVIMENTO LIKE '%Deleted exam%')
   AND C.CD_ATENDIMENTO = :CD_ATENDIMENTO
 ORDER BY 2
```

}

Comment: Yes, I'll do like you wrote in the last edit! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a view in the database and select from the view?
Putting as big part of the select as  much as possible into the DB reduces the number of developer/tool errors in the application layer.

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameters to a view? As you can see, the query has two parameters: I need to filter by :CD_ATENDIMENTO and/or :Pedido.

Comment: No. You have to **include each column** in the select part that you want to filter when using a view. In your case, the union goes into the view, and the where clause gets simpler. Tell us if VS can handle that. Take use of he tip above with extra parentheses.